# Show that two triangles have the same orthocenter

Tags: geometry

> $M$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle PQR$. Let $ME\parallel PR$ intersecting $PQ$ at $E$; $MF\parallel PQ$ intersecting $PR$ at $F$. Line $EF$ intersects $\odot(PQR)$ at $A$ and $B$. Show that $M$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABZ$ where $PZ$ is a diameter of $\odot PQR$.
>
> [image: Diagram]

I can prove $EF\perp MZ$. Since $ME\parallel PR$ and $MF\parallel PQ$, $\angle EMQ=\angle FMR=\dfrac\pi2$. And $\angle QEM=\angle QPR=\angle MFR$. So $\triangle MQE\sim\triangle MRF$. Let $\dfrac{ME}{MQ}=\dfrac{MF}{MR}=k$. Let's use complex numbers. Let $M=0$, then $E=-\mathrm ikQ$ and $F=ikR$. As a well kown property, $MRZQ$ is a parallelogram. So $Z-M=Q+R$. And $F-E=ik(Q+R)$. So $\dfrac{F-E}{Z-M}\in\mathrm i\mathbb R$, then $EF\perp MZ$.

But I have trouble proving $BM\perp AZ$ because I haven't found any geometric property of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Try to show that $\triangle AMF \sim \triangle QAE$?

Comment: @Hypernova Thanks for your idea. I can prove it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Mark intersection of $QR$ and $AZ$ as $H$. Mark center of circumcircle of $\triangle PQR$ as $O$. Mark mid point of $M$ and $O$ as $N$ , this point is the center of nine point circle. This nine point circle must also be that of triangle $ABZ$ if $M$ is its orthocenter. To show this consider following observations in accurate drawing:

1- $H$ is the foot of altitude $PH$, passing $M$, of $\triangle PQR$ and nine point circle passes $H$.

2- $\triangle ABZ$ is isosceles, i.e $AZ=AB$ .

3- Nine point circle is tangent to $BZ$ at point $K$.

4- Points $A$, $M$, $N$, $O$ and $K$ are co-linear, so $AK$ is altitude of $\triangle ABZ$. This is sufficient to find that nine point circle also passes the foot of other two altitudes of $\triangle ABZ$ so $M$ is orthocenter of $ABZ$ too.